# add text on image using Javascript and Canvas

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I have a question about this topic 
 [How to add text on image using Javascript and Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116851/how-to-add-text-on-image-using-javascript-and-canvas)

I am unable to get the image in the first go. But image load when I hit refresh.

This is my code from php file:

```
<canvas id="canvas"> </canvas>
<form class="myNameForm">
    <?php echo '<img style="display:none" class="myimage" 
        src="./save/'.$filenamewithoutExt.'" crossorigin="anonymous">';?>
    <label class="inpLable" for="input">Enter Name: </label>
    <input class="inp" maxlength="12" type="text" id="inp"/>
</form>
```

This is my code from js file:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = $('img').width();
    canvas.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    canvas.height = $('img').height();
    ctx.drawImage($('img').get(0), 0, 0);
    $(document).on('input', '#inp', function() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.font = "20pt Verdana";
        ctx.drawImage($('img').get(0), 0, 0);
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillText($(this).val(), 170, 590);
    });
};
```

Comment: Post your code, show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: try to use fabric.js

Comment: @Mirakurun i have updated the question and added the code.

Comment: the problem is because of "images load asynchronously" but i am unable to fix it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009528/javascript-image-only-loads-on-refresh

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is `<img>` has `display: none` thus it can **not** have `offsetWidth`

Answer (score 2):

I have made small changes in your code

```
<canvas id="canvas"> </canvas>
<img style="display: none" class="myimage" src='https://picsum.photos/200/200'/>
<label class="inpLable" for="input">Enter Name: </label>
<input class="inp" maxlength="12" type="text" id="inp"/>
```

And JS

```
$('#inp').on('input', function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = $('img').width();
  canvas.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  canvas.height = $('img').height();
  ctx.drawImage($('img').get(0), 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.font = "20px Verdana";
  ctx.drawImage($('img').get(0), 0, 0);
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillText($(this).val(), 10, 50);
});
```

Here I have created a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkjw5raq/1/)

Comment: But the image load when the user starts typing. I want the image to load when page loads. not when user starts typing.

Comment: So you want the image only to show after a refresh, but show what was typed before the refresh? Canvases are cleared when the page unloads, which includes during a refresh. So you'll have to store the user input somehow (either server-side, or locally with session storage or local storage or something similar), and then load the text from there on page load and re-create the canvas image.